How do you visualise the conditional esperance of your outcome variable depending on the predictor?
I've read several posts regarding the choice of distributions and link functions for GLMs. Although I'm far from understanding it all, what I've gathered is that the purpose of the link function is to linearise the relation $E(Y|X) \sim X$ and ensure that the hypothesis associated with the chosen distribution are respected (equal mean and variance for Poisson for example).
My question is how can you see if the link function chosen does linearise the relation between the conditional mean of Y and the predictor. Is it by plotting $Y \sim g^{-1}(X)$ from your data and assuming that the observed values of Y in the data are representative of $E(Y)$ ?
Thanks

This falls under the rubric of "goodness of fit testing."  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=goodness+of+fit+glm.
